# Assets/script/Behavior/FighterStateBehavior.cs(19,25): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `FighterStateBehavior' to `FighterStates'

Tags: c#

I have an error on this code `fighter.currentState = behaviorState;`
and it said:

> "Assets/script/Behavior/FighterStateBehavior.cs(19,25): error CS0029: Cannot implicitly convert type `FighterStateBehavior' to`FighterStates'"

What should I do?

```
public class FighterStateBehavior : StateMachineBehaviour {
    public FighterStateBehavior behaviorState;

    public float horizontalForce;
    public float verticalForce;

    protected Fighter fighter;

    override public void  OnStateEnter(Animator animator, 
                                        AnimatorStateInfo stateInfo, int layerIndex){
    if (fighter == null) {
        fighter = animator.gameObject.GetComponent<Fighter> ();
    }

    //error script down from here 
    fighter.currentState = behaviorState;

    fighter.body.AddRelativeForce (new Vector3 (0, verticalForce,0));

}
```

Comment: The error you are seeing is fairly self explanatory, what exactly do you not understand about it?

Comment: Yes, `fighter.currentState` is of type `FighterStates` while `behaviorState` is of type `FighterStateBehavior`.

Comment: when i click error report at the console bar , it direct me to this script 
" fighter.currentState = behaviorState; " and i try to change it to " fighter.currentState = BehaviorState; "  , but it makes new error and it said  (error CS0103: The name `BehaviorState' does not exist in the current context)  i don't know what should i do cause i am new in programming , and i am really sorry if my english is mess up